# Issue loading XML + Flash Player 10.0.45.2 on Windows XP SP3 with IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, windows-xp, actionscript-2, flashplayer-10

I have a question about FP 10.0.45.2, on a Windows XP SP3 machine within IE 8.  Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I was handed an AS2 elearning course to debug for a client.  The client is running the above set up.  While testing this course locally on my machine, I receive no issues.  However, when the client tests the same files locally on their machine, the course runs, but fails to load the external quiz.xml file.  We turned on Compatibility Mode in IE, but this did not help.

Can anyone suggest a reason for this problem?  Is there perhaps a security setting in IE8 that the client needs to activate or deactivate?  Thanks any suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh Flash.  The file in question, that was sent to me via the client, was corrupt and would not render in ie8 - Win XP machine.  However, if I checked it on Win 7 - IE9 it would.  So annoying.  All I did was copy the existing frames out of the fla, created a new fla and pasted the frames in.  Compiled it and viola, it worked.  Thanks Flash for wasting 2 days of my life.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the file path to the XML correct on his machine?
2. Are you both running on the same platform? If not, then there could be filepath nuances with Mac vs PC.

The best way to troubleshoot this is to open the Network inspector in the browser and see if there is an error being generated when trying to load the XML file in.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly!!!  The path to the xml is relative to the file within the as2 code.  We unzipped the same package, and into a main directory.  I'm on Win7 running IE9 (in IE8 mode).  Same Flash Player Version.  Anything else that might ring a bell would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does the page in question have the "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" setting set? That would cause this problem. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/07/downloads-and-flash-fail-when-do-not-save-encrypted-pages-to-disk-is-set.aspx

Comment: I'm thinking the issue has to do with an include file that's pointing to a .as file via a relative path (../directory/file.as).  Could this be the reason the page is freezing at this line of code?  Are there any known bugs associated with using the "#include" key word?  Thanks, any additional help is appreciated!